# Unable to proxy Webgoat localhost requests in spite of doing the necessary configurations

Tags: owasp, zap, webgoat

I am new to Webgoat and followed all the steps required to configure Firefox and Webgoat.

- 1 Setup Local proxies in webgoat to run on localhost 8090
- 2 Exported the certificate and imported it in Firefox
- 3 Setup Proxy in Firefox and removed everything present in "No proxy for".
- 4 Webgoat is running on 8080 and ZAP on 8090 - two different ports.

I am able to see the requests from other sites like google, youtube, etc. in ZAP but unable to see the Webgoat (localhost) requests even after refreshing the page multiple times.

Is there something I am missing out or do I need to check anything else too ?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is an up-to-date version of Firefox you now need to visit `about:config` and set `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` to `true`

Reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581